# How to handle errors in Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

I'm trying to echo something via Ajax but I'm not getting any output. So I would add a pair of error handling to see what is working wrong.

How can I add simple error handling code to see where the error is?

## page.html

```
<body>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Load" />
    <div id="feedback"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
```

## page.php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GE['name'])) {
     echo $name = $_GET['name'];
  }
?>
```

## ajax.js

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        data: {
            name: name
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#feedback').html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Pop quiz: When you open `page.php?name=foo` in your browser, what happens?

Comment: nothing is being displayed!! There is no errors in the console too...

Comment: Probably gives an internal server error since you wrote `$_GE['name']` wrong

Comment: Right-on. That's the first thing you have to fix. Check [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/18771)

Comment: Yes it was typo ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this from your local drive? If so, your browser will block the request due to null origin policy.
As far as debugging goes, the best option you have is to go to your developer tools' network tab and it will show it going through.

Edit: Nevermind the first part I noticed you are using a php server.